# Magento 2.3.0 Custom UI Component custom admin form How to Upload image?

Tags: image-upload, magento2.3.0

In Magento 2.3.0 How to Upload the image into the custom admin ui component form ?

I have tried many codes but "The file was not uploaded" error occured into the uploading

My Code:

> adminhtml/ui_component/custom_form.xml

```
            <field name="swatch_image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Swatch Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Cirklestudio_Customproduct/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customproduct/customoption/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </field>
```

> adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
<div class="file-uploader-preview">
    <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
        <img
            class="preview-image"
            tabindex="0"
            event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
            attr="
                src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                alt: $file.name">
    </a>

    <div class="actions">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="action-remove"
            data-role="delete-button"
            attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
            click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
            <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
<div class="file-uploader-meta">
    <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
</div>
```

This is my Upload Controller

> Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Customoption\Upload.php

```
<?php
namespace Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Customoption;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/** * Class Upload */ 
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action { 
/** 
* Image uploader * 
* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader */ protected $imageUploader;

/**
* Upload constructor.
*
* @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
*/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
}

/**
 * Check admin permissions for this controller
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Cirklestudio_Customproduct::customoption');
}

/**
 * Upload file controller action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('logo');

        $result['cookie'] = [
            'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
            'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
    }
    return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
}

}
```

Model (image uploader)

> Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model\ImageUploader.php

```
<?php

/** 
* Simple Hello World Module 
** @category QaisarSatti 
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld 
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti 
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com * */
namespace Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model;

/** 
* Catalog image uploader */ 
class ImageUploader { 
    /** 
    * Core file storage database 
    * 
    * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database */ 
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

/**
 * Media directory object (writable).
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
 */
protected $mediaDirectory;

/**
 * Uploader factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
 */
private $uploaderFactory;

/**
 * Store manager
 *
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * Base tmp path
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $baseTmpPath;

/**
 * Base path
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $basePath;

/**
 * Allowed extensions
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $allowedExtensions;

/**
 * ImageUploader constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param string $baseTmpPath
 * @param string $basePath
 * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    $baseTmpPath,
    $basePath,
    $allowedExtensions
) {
    $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    $this->basePath = $basePath;
    $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
}

/**
 * Set base tmp path
 *
 * @param string $baseTmpPath
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
{
    $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
}

/**
 * Set base path
 *
 * @param string $basePath
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setBasePath($basePath)
{
    $this->basePath = $basePath;
}

/**
 * Set allowed extensions
 *
 * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
{
    $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
}

/**
 * Retrieve base tmp path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBaseTmpPath()
{
    return $this->baseTmpPath;
}

/**
 * Retrieve base path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBasePath()
{
    return $this->basePath;
}

/**
 * Retrieve base path
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getAllowedExtensions()
{
    return $this->allowedExtensions;
}

/**
 * Retrieve path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string $imageName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
{
    return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
}

/**
 * Checking file for moving and move it
 *
 * @param string $imageName
 *
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
{
    $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
    $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

    $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
    $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

    try {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
            $baseTmpImagePath,
            $baseImagePath
        );
        $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
            $baseTmpImagePath,
            $baseImagePath
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
        );
    }

    return $imageName;
}

/**
 * Checking file for save and save it to tmp dir
 *
 * @param string $fileId
 *
 * @return string[]
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
{
    $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();

    $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

    $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));

    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
     */

    $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
    $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
    $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
    $result['name'] = $result['file'];

    if (isset($result['file'])) {
        try {
            $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

}
```

> di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Cirklestudio\Customproduct\CustomproductImageUpload" type="Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">test/tmp</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Customoption\Upload">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Cirklestudio\Customproduct\CustomproductImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: show your code that you have tried.

Comment: Please check code

Comment: try using this instead of **fileUploader** `<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>`

Comment: I tried but not working same error occured "The file was not uploaded"

Comment: How to modify the extended sales order grid in Magento 2 anyone?

Answer (score 0):

**Now issue is solve try this changes**

> adminhtml/ui_component/custom_form.xml

```
<field name="swatch_image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Cirklestudio_Customproduct/image-preview</item>
             <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customproduct/customoption/upload" >
                    <param name="target_element_id">swatch_image</param>
                    <param name="type">image</param>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

> adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is your Upload Controller

> Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Customoption\Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Customoption;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public $imageUploader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('swatch_image');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

Model (image uploader)

> Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model\ImageUploader.php

```
<?php

namespace Cirklestudio\Customproduct\Model;

class ImageUploader
{
    private $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    private $mediaDirectory;
    private $uploaderFactory;
    private $storeManager;
    private $logger;
    public $baseTmpPath;
    public $basePath;
    public $allowedExtensions;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = "Test/temp";
        $this->basePath = "Test";
        $this->allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    }
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];
        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try
            {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```